# What problems may using the MIME type application/json cause?

Tags: javascript, json, cross-browser, content-type, mime-types

I am working on  a web service the needs to return JSON data.  [I read that I should use application/json](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/477816/the-right-json-content-type) but am not sure what problems this may cause?

For example, will older browsers support it? (IE6+, FF, Opera, etc.)

Or is it possible that users behind corporate firewalls/proxy servers block the mime type application/json?

What, if any, problems have you had following this advice?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's consider IE. Say you have a hidden iFrame which you use to request a file download. For example

```
<iframe src="getFile?id=123">
```

Now, the server may send a JSON-encoded error message like

```
{
    error: 'File 123 does not exist',
    retryLater: false
}
```

If that error message is sent as `application/json`, a download dialog will appear, because the JSON text is mistaken for the actual file.

On the other hand, a MIME type of `text/plain` will cause the message to be rendered in the iFrame, and you can extract it, and transform it into a fancy pop-up or something using JScript.

---

(Edit)

Real-world example: [EXTJS Fileupload - Problem with IE8 security bar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4471920/)

Comment: Thanks pumbaa80, and also considering what Eric said below, it looks  like using text/x-json may be best.

Comment: I only realized just now that `text/x-json` brings up a download dialog too, so you need `text/plain` for the iframe contents. Also, [uploading](http://yuilibrary.com/projects/yui2/ticket/2528941) is a much more useful example than downloading.

Answer (score 1):

This has been discussed before:

[What is the correct JSON content type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/477816/the-right-json-content-type)

Any firewalls that block the MIME type will cause problems with any AJAX-style web apps, so I really wouldn't worry about it.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, Yes I read the dicussion you pointed out. I was looking for more real world concrete examples, that some SO user may have experiences. Like Pumbaa80 answer below. Good to know about firewalls. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Having just had a long fight with IE8 myself with this I found that if you're loading the json into an iframe as text/plain, IE8 will wrap this in a  tag.  If you then fetch the content out with innerHTML and try to parse this as json, it'll fail.

I ended up having to send the content as text/html, which just seems totally wrong, but works in IE and doesn't seem to mess up other browsers more modern AJAX handling.